# how to run SSIS packages from within AWS

Tags: authentication, ssis

I would like to know if there's a way to run ssis packages without using windows authentication.If running ssis package using sql authentication is possible, i will take that as well.

Comment: I need step by step example so that i can test it in my environment

Comment: I'm assuming you mean using connections that authenticate to SQL Server like an OLE DB Source or Destination? If so, then yes this is possible. You just need a sql authentication account setup on your source and/or destination database.